# A PART of the group who damages/damage?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

This is not the same as the other topics.

> "I don't want to be *a part* of THE GROUP who **damages/damage** the reputation of their own company."

What you are trying to say is, you don't want to *include* yourself in THE GROUP who **damages/damages** a company's reputation?

What is the correct verb here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/group_1?q=group)...

> **group** noun
>    ***countable + singular or plural verb***
>   a number of people or things that are together in the same place or that are connected in some way
>   Example usage: *A group of us **is/are** going to the theatre this evening.*

Although it's not specifically mentioned there, I should point out that AmE has always tended to treat similar "composite entity" nouns *(**family, company, [the] government], [the] police,...**)* as singular in all contexts.

BrE is more flexible on this point, and thus probably more likely than AmE to treat ***group*** as plural in contexts where the relevant verb more logically attaches to *each individual* person or thing within the group, rather than to the group as a single entity. That's to say, in BrE we often treat ***a group*** as *syntactically* equivalent to ***members of a group*** if that's a better *semantic* match for the context.

---

In OP's specific context, the relativizer ***who*** only really works with a plural verb form *(a group who **damage** reputations)*. With a singular verb, it would have to be *a group **that damages** reputations*.

Comment: Right, so when you are focusing on "the group" it will be "I don't want to be a part of the GROUP who DAMAGE the reputation of a company" right?. This, is a bit confusing to me because I was thinking if the subject in this sentece is **"I"** or "**THE GROUP"** that's why.

Comment: The subject of the whole *sentence* is indeed ***I***, but that's got nothing to do with the part we're looking at, since it could just as well have been preceded by plural ***My friends** don't want to be part of...* An example where the relevant component ***is*** the subject would be *The group who support racism **are** not welcome here*. Where as explained earlier, it's the use of ***who*** that forces us to treat it as plural. That's not the case with *The group **that** support / supports racism **are / is** not welcome here*, where both are fine to me (as a Brit??!! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**group**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/group)

> a number of people or things that are put together or **considered as a unit**

If we simplify that definition: a group **is** a unit. In the phrase "a group are a unit" the verb does not match neither the subject nor the object.

The example provided with the above definition backs up this reasoning

> *This group of chemicals **is** known to be harmful to people with asthma.*

So, the correct form is the singular one: **damages**